# Sandboxing in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, firejail

I want to run some of my programs like skype,firefox,office suite in side seperate VMS..in Linux..Is it possible to install only an application inside a vm without installing the whole os..also i dont want to manually start the application inside vm everytime..i want to click the icon and the application starts running inside a vm itself automatically.. something like firejail but using vm instead..how to achieve this.. please can someone guide me in this direction

Comment: It depends what your exact requirements for "sandboxing" are. One common one is containers. Search for "Linux containers" as there are a number of different technologies that can be used. But without clearer requirements it is difficult to say whether that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Actually i want to have a more secure working environment for certain applications like browser,mail clients etc. Like the applications prone to attack by malicious actors..I know we can run application within containers but aren't they less secure in comparison to a vm